# BoxHelper makes BoxGeometry gigantic

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

**EDIT**

I found out that the giant box occurs whenever I want to add the HelperBox, I made [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yx3vb9Lt/) and here nothing influences the size of the second box. However, in my code, there's something interfering with my box because when I add the Helper to the scene it messes up my second box as you can see here: you can see the outlines of the giant box [on this screenshot](https://puu.sh/sUYox/2cf72d99d0.png) and if I zoom out some more you can see that they're all covered [in the giant blue box.](https://puu.sh/sUYB3/df8f52494e.png) I can't figure out why this is happening... Especially not since the JSFiddle just works fine. (Perhaps the messed up outlines of the box is an indicator to something?)

**ORIGINAL**

I'm trying to check the collision of 2 boxes in THREE, I was getting some results I wasn't expecting and implemented the THREE.BoxHelper. When I use it on my first box, nothing's wrong, but when I add the helper on my second box it appears so gigantic... I can't seem to find where I'm going wrong. I based myself on [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/3D_collision_detection/Bounding_volume_collision_detection_with_THREE.js).

A screenshot of what I'm getting visually:

[image: The orange helper box is gigantic.]

This is the main part of the code triggering this:

```
const makeTestCube = () => {
  testBox = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0099})//PINK
  );
  testBox.position.set(0, 0, 20);
  testBoxBbox = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3());
  testBoxBbox.setFromObject(testBox);
  const testBoxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(testBoxBbox, 0xCC6600); //ORANGE
  testBox.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  scene.add(testBox);
  scene.add(testBoxHelper);
};

const makeAnotherTestCube = () => {
  anotherTestBox = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x990000})//RED This is the small box in the giant box
  );
  anotherTestBox.position.set(0, 0, 30);
  anotherTestBoundingBox = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3());
  anotherTestBoundingBox.setFromObject(anotherTestBox);
  const anotherTestBoxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(anotherTestBox, 0xCC6600);// This is the giant box (Orange)
  anotherTestBox.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  scene.add(anotherTestBox);
  scene.add(anotherTestBoxHelper);
};
```

And this is my whole script:

```
import sets from './data/sets';

import ColladaLoader from 'three-collada-loader';

import BufferLoader from './modules/sound/BufferLoader';
import SpawnObject from './modules/render/SpawnObject';
import Controls from './modules/util/Controls';

import io from 'socket.io-client';
import {isEmpty} from 'lodash';

const OrbitControls = require(`./modules/util/OrbitControls`)(THREE);
const DeviceOrientationControls = require(`./modules/util/DeviceOrientationControls`);

// const PointerLockControls = require(`./modules/util/PointerLockControls`);

let scene, camera, renderer, VRcontrols, element, cameraBox, testBox, anotherTestBox, cameraBoundingBox, testBoundingBox, anotherTestBoundingBox;
let testBoxBbox;
let audioCtx, bufferLoader;
let socket, controlData;
let player, mobile;
let moveForward = false, moveBackward = false, moveLeft = false, moveRight = false;
let camX = 0;
const camY = 0;
let camZ = 2;
let mousedown = false;
const camSpeed = .1;
const notes = [];
let devices = [];
const collidableMeshList = [];

const mobilecheck = () => {
  mobile = false;
  (function(a) {if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) mobile = true;})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);
  return mobile;
};

const init = () => {

  mobilecheck();

  socket = io(`/`);

  socket.on(`init`, handleWSInit);
  socket.on(`dataTransfer`, handleWSData);

  window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

  if (!mobile) {
    document.addEventListener(`keydown`, useArrowDown);
    document.addEventListener(`keyup`, useArrowUp);
    document.addEventListener(`mousedown`, () => mousedown = true);
    document.addEventListener(`mouseup`, () => mousedown = false);
    document.addEventListener(`mousemove`, e => {
      if (mousedown) {
        const rotateAngle = Math.PI / 4;
        player.rotateY(rotateAngle * e.movementX * .1);
      }
    });
  }

};

const handleWSInit = users => {
  const {id: socketId} = socket;

  users = users.map(u => {
    if (u.socketId === socketId) u.isMe = true;
    return u;
  });

  devices = users;

  if (window.location.href.indexOf(`controls`) > - 1) {
    const controls = new Controls(socket, devices);
    console.log(controls);
    return;
  }

  document.querySelector(`main`).classList.remove(`controls`);

  loadAudio();

};

const loadAudio = () => {
  audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(audioCtx);

  bufferLoader.load(sets.drums);
    // .then(data => spawnObject(data));


  initEnvironment();
};

const handleWSData = data => {
  if (data !== undefined || data !== null || isEmpty(data)) controlData = data;

  devices = devices.map(u => {
    u.yo = false;
    return u;
  });

};

const spawnObject = data => {

  for (let i = 0;i < 5;i ++) {
    const bol = new SpawnObject(`object.dae`, audioCtx, data[0], scene, true);
    notes.push(bol);
    collidableMeshList.push((notes[0].scene.children[2]));

  }
};

const initEnvironment = () => {
  console.log(notes);
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    1, 1000
  );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  element = renderer.domElement;
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  //PLAYER
  player = new THREE.Object3D();
  player.add(camera);
  player.velocity = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  makeTestCube();
  // makeCameraBox();
  makeAnotherTestCube();
  scene.add(player);

  camera.position.set(0, 0, 2); // first-player view
  player.position.set(0, 0, 0);
  player.rotation.y = - Math.PI / 2.0;

  VRcontrols = mobile ? new DeviceOrientationControls(camera) : new OrbitControls(camera);

  //LIGHTS
  const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
  light.position.set(0, 0, 9);
  light.castShadow = true;
  light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
  light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
  scene.add(light);

  //FLOOR
  const matFloor = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
  const geoFloor = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2000, 1, 2000);
  const mshFloor = new THREE.Mesh(geoFloor, matFloor);

  matFloor.color.set(0x212E39);
  mshFloor.receiveShadow = true;
  mshFloor.position.set(0, - 1, 0);

  scene.add(mshFloor);


  const loader = new ColladaLoader();

  loader.load(`../assets/environment.dae`, collada => {
    collada.scene.traverse(child => {
      child.castShadow = true;
      child.receiveShadow = true;
    });
    scene.add(collada.scene);
    animate();
  });

};

// const makeCameraBox = () => {
//   const cameraBoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3);
//   const cameraBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ffff});
//   cameraBox = new THREE.Mesh(cameraBoxGeometry, cameraBoxMaterial);
//   cameraBox.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
//   const cameraBoxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(cameraBox, 0x0000ff);
//   cameraBoundingBox = new THREE.Box3(
//     cameraBox.geometry.boundingBox.min,
//     cameraBox.geometry.boundingBox.max
//   );
//   cameraBoundingBox.setFromObject(cameraBox);
//   // player.add(cameraBoundingBox);
//   scene.add(cameraBoxHelper);
//   scene.add(cameraBox);
// };

const makeTestCube = () => {
  testBox = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0099})//PINK
  );
  testBox.position.set(0, 0, 20);
  testBoxBbox = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3());
  testBoxBbox.setFromObject(testBox);
  const testBoxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(testBoxBbox, 0xCC6600); //ORANGE
  testBox.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  scene.add(testBox);
  scene.add(testBoxHelper);
};

const makeAnotherTestCube = () => {
  anotherTestBox = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x990000})//RED This is the small box in the giant box
  );
  anotherTestBox.position.set(0, 0, 30);
  anotherTestBoundingBox = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3());
  anotherTestBoundingBox.setFromObject(anotherTestBox);
  const anotherTestBoxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(anotherTestBox, 0xCC6600);// This is the giant box (Orange)
  anotherTestBox.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  scene.add(anotherTestBox);
  scene.add(anotherTestBoxHelper);
};

const moveCamera = () => {
  // TODO: find movementX (0= no movement, 1-... = movement)
  //dan -> player.rotateY(rotateAngle * e.movementX * .1);
  const movementX = VRcontrols.object.rotation._y;
  const rotateAngle = Math.PI / 4;
  console.log(VRcontrols.deviceOrientation);

  //player.rotateY(rotateAngle * movementX * .1);
  // notes.forEach(i => {
  //   i.audioCtx.listener.positionX.value = camX + window.innerWidth / 2;
  //   i.audioCtx.listener.positionZ.value = camZ + 300;
  //   i.audioCtx.listener.positionY.value = camY + window.innerHeight / 2;
  // });
  //
  switch (controlData) {
  case `up`:
    camZ -= camSpeed;
    break;
  case `down`:
    camZ += camSpeed;
    break;
  case `left`:
    camX -= camSpeed;
    break;
  case `right`:
    camX += camSpeed;
    break;
  }

  camera.position.set(camX, camY, camZ);
  VRcontrols.update();
};

//CODE BENEATH NEEDS TO BE LESS DIRTY.

const useArrowDown = e => {
  switch (e.key) {
  case `z`:
    moveForward = true;
    break;
  case `s`:
    moveBackward = true;
    break;
  case `q`:
    moveLeft = true;
    break;
  case `d`:
    moveRight = true;
    break;
  }
};

const useArrowUp = e => {
  switch (e.key) {
  case `z`:
    moveForward = false;
    break;
  case `s`:
    moveBackward = false;
    break;
  case `q`:
    moveLeft = false;
    break;
  case `d`:
    moveRight = false;
    break;
  }
};


const animate = () => {

  if (mobile) {
    moveCamera();
  }

  if (moveForward) player.position.z -= 5;
  if (moveBackward) player.position.z += 5;
  if (moveLeft) player.position.x -= 5;
  if (moveRight) player.position.x += 5;

  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

  renderer.gammaInput = true;
  renderer.gammaOutput = true;

  renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd, 1);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  //
  // if (testBoundingBox.intersectsBox(cameraBoundingBox)) {
  //   console.log(`intersection`);
  // }

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

};


init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling this piece of code fixed it for me, I do *not* understand why, though.

```
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

renderer.gammaInput = true;
renderer.gammaOutput = true;
renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

No offense, your variable names are awful. It's incredibly confusing as to what's what here.

Try this. Change this line:

```
const anotherTestBoxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(anotherTestBox, 0xCC6600);
```

To:

```
const anotherTestBoxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(anotherTestBoundingBox, 0xCC6600);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've gone pretty bad with the variable names for testing this. It's because I hoped I would be testing this for max 10 minutes and find what the problem was... It has already been a while longer now. Also, your suggestion renders the same as I had at first. (That's why I added in commentary what every box should represent, "box1" and "box2" would be as confusing as what I have now, don't you think?)

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what the problem would be then. I would create a fiddle as it will help others debug.

Comment: @WestLangley nothing more you can do than keep on trying, I suppose. Which is also what I'm doing right now fyi.

Comment: @Kevin Fair enough. It is just that asking others to debug your code is a very bad habit to get into.

Comment: @WestLangley Hm, why are you assuming that I haven't tried a lot of options before coming to here? I totally agree with your opinion, but I don't know why you'd think that I just encountered this problem and instead of looking into it I'd just post it here and wait for an answer? Until now I've been changing my code to see if differences start to occur... I've updated my post with more information and observations... I'm not trying to let other people make my project, I just try to solve the problem, perhaps with the vision of others? Unless you still don't agree with me? I'm happy to hear it

Comment: @Kevin I am not assuming anything. I have no idea how long you have worked on this. Ask questions about three.js. Avoid help-me-debug-my-code questions. That is my advice to everyone. Anyway, if I notice what is wrong, I'll tell you. :)

Comment: Hm, the comparison between "three.js questions" and "help-me-debug-my-code questions" makes clear what you were trying to point out in the previous comment. Well I've been trying to just start a scene from scratch and build it up to where I am now and see where it goes wrong. I'll definitely keep in mind what you just posted :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130977/discussion-between-kevin-and-westlangley).

Comment: I don't have mod rights. Can we delete the question? So far this is not helpful to the community. OP's jsfiddle fixes the issue and the issue is somewhere in OP's code, not in the intent, approach or pattern.